# In angular2 typescript, how to execute code when the user navigate to other page from a particular single page?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I need to execute the code only when the user navigate to another page from a particular page only.
ie, the source page will be same always and destination page will be different. Code must be executed when moved only from source page

Is there any possible way to do this? I'm new to angular. 
Hoping to hear from you.

Comment: You can use query params when navigating. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use Routing In which the component will be activated only if the user is visiting that page.

Answer (score 0):

The best router for Angular2 in my opinion is uirouter. Here I leave an example:

```
import { UIRouterModule } from "@uirouter/angular";


let loginState = { name: "login", url: "",  component: LoginComponent };
let homeState = { name: "home", url: "/home",  component: HomeComponent };
let adminState = { name: "admin", url: "/admin",  component: AdminComponent };

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        UIRouterModule.forRoot({ states: [ loginState, homeState, adminState ], useHash: true })
],
exports: [
    UIRouterModule
]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```